# What is the equivalent of Mathematica's ToExpression in Racket?

Tags: parsing, scheme, expression, racket

I am looking for something similar to [ToExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html) that is available in Mathematica. I just want to convert a string to an expression, and evaluate the expression. As a first pass, my strings will include only numbers and arithmetic operators, and not even parentheses.

If I need to write it, please point me in the direction of the appropriate pre-defined modules/definitions which I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this parser for infix expressions.

http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/infix.plt/1/0/planet-docs/manual/index.html

Here is a small example (it takes a while for the library to install - it seems it old Schematics test suite takes forever to install these days - I need to switch to a builtin one).

```
#lang at-exp racket
(require (planet soegaard/infix)
         (planet soegaard/infix/parser))
(display (format "1+2*3 is ~a\n" @${1+2*3} ))

(parse-expression #'here (open-input-string "1+2*3"))
```

The output will be:

```
1+2*3 is 7
.#<syntax:6:21 (#%infix (+ 1 (* 2 3)))>
```

The function parse-expression parses the expression in the string and
returns a syntax-object that resembles the output of ToExpression.

Answer (score 1):

Does the section on [dynamic evaluation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/reflection.html) apply to your question?  You can parse strings into expressions by using a combination of [read](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29) and [open-input-string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stringport.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._open-input-string%29%29).  The resulting expressions can be evaluated, with or without the help of a [sandbox](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html).

Comment: Nice work! I can't believe you answered that question without saying "eval". D'oh!

Comment: Uh oh.  Did I screw up?  I'm tone-deaf on the Internet... :(

Comment: Nope, I was genuinely amused. See, the joke was that *I* said eval, while congratulating you for not saying ... uh, cf. E.B. White's comment about humor and the frog :).

Comment: @dyoo Is there some sample code that uses a combination of "read" and "open-input-string" that would serve as an example?

Comment: `open-input-string` takes a string and produces an input port.  `read` takes an input port and produces an s-expression.  `(define an-expr (read (open-input-string "(prn 'hi)"))))`, for example, will have `an-expr` refer to a value that we can process more easily than a string, since it has structure.  Then we've got libraries, like the ones cited in the answer, that can evaluate this structured expression.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html